# How can I make this menu using only ul, li and css?

Tags: css, menu, horizontallist

I would like to do this using CSS:

[image]

Ssing only `ul` `li`, and `a` elements. The red bullets would be invisible.

How can I do this? I've tried using `float:left` for the horizontal outer bullet list and a normal vertical bullet list for the inner one, but it did not works.

Is there a better way than bullet list?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: No it's for a personnal project and I want to use ol li as restriction only because of the good implementation in differents browser including mobile browser..

Comment: The picture is confusing. Could you describe it better?

Comment: So which one is the outer bullet list and which one is the inner bullet list?

Comment: I need, on the first "floor" a number and a label under it which describe the number. Exemple, the number of views. On it's right, another number and it's label is something like the number of shares. On it's rigght, there is the title of a news by exemple. On the second floor, there is an image, under the two numbers and on it's right, aligned on the title, there is something like an abstract. Two floors

Comment: @bazmegakapa when I have tried with outer and inner list, but I am not sure that there is a need of implementing inner and outer list..

Comment: @Pier-alexandreBouchard I don't see a point in solving this with an ordered list. In what sense is this an ordered list? Try to keep the markup semantic.

Comment: I edited: there is no need of an ordered list. ul, no ol. Excuse me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just going to throw this out there as a viable solution. Why not use div elements? Here's an example:

CSS --

```
.container {
    width   : 400px;
    margin  : 0;
    padding : 0;
}
.col {
    display : inline-block;
    width   : 100px;
    vertical-align : top;
}
.col.double {
    width : 200px;
}
```

HTML --

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">9</div>
        <div class="col">0</div>
        <div class="col">TITLE</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col double">{image}</div>
        <div class="col">text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/a9m76/1/

Comment: Yeah, almost, but under 9, in your exemple, I need a label explaining the signification of the number.. and 9 could be centered on this label. It's the reason why I wanted to use bullets..

Comment: @Pier-alexandreBouchard http://jsfiddle.net/a9m76/2/, `text-align:center` and a `<br />` tag took care of that.

Comment: @Pier-alexandreBouchard You can change to using two containers to make the elements line-up more like your mock-up: http://jsfiddle.net/a9m76/3/